# .htaccess Causes Problem With Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use this Javascript code to mark threads as favourite:

```
function fave(tid){
 xmlhttp = createXHR();
 if(xmlhttp){
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
    get("fave"+tid).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "thread?act=fave&tid="+tid+"&ajax=1", true);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
 }
}
```

My .htaccess file contains this line `RewriteRule ^thread/([0-9]+)? /thread?tid=$1 [L]`, which turns `/thread?tid=1234` in more pretty `/thread/1234`.

With the first URL everything works fine, but `/thread/1234` causes an error.
[image]
Click on the underlined link returns:
[image]

Response HTML is a copy of a whole page!
Why the same document with the only difference between `/thread?tid=1234` and `/thread/1234` URLs behaves in different ways?

**UPDATE:**

```
RewriteRule ^thread/([0-9]+)? /thread?tid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The improved .htaccess line solved the problem.

Comment: thread?act=fave&tid="+tid+"&ajax=1 doesn't exactly match your rewrite rule, so I'd assume that it's not being rewritten

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the [QSA] modifier in your htaccess.

At the first look, your problem is that the ajax=1 and act=fave values do not get appended after rewriting the URL.

So the RewriteRule should be:

```
RewriteRule ^thread/([0-9]+)? /thread?tid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And then your code:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "thread/"+tid+"?ajax=1&act=fave", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be problem within capturing the AJAX event in PHP - try to var_dump the GET vars ... I think that you will miss "the ajax identifier" :)